# Find break lines in html using python

Tags: python, html, line, break, findall

I'm trying to find all line breaks (br) but also change of line when within paragraphs (p) of an html website.
I have this code

```
breaks = re.findall('br<>\n', html)
print len(breaks)
```

but it's not working. Any help

Comment: shouldn't the HTML breaks be `<br>` or  `<br />`?

Comment: And your code will only look for breaks that are inmediately followed by newlines (`\n`); do you want that as an OR condition or an AND ?

Comment: Please show us some sample input and the output you expect to get.

Comment: I don't have an output example. I've down the same with links in an html page, and it worked! I get the len of the links list and it shows, this doesn't show up. I want to be an OR, so that it shows all br and all line changes

Comment: @Ralf the thing with <br> <br /> worked. What about line changes when a paragraph starts automatically a new line?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want, since you don't show example inputs and outputs.

But if you are looking to split after an `<br>` tag OR an newline, you could try this:

```
# included many vairations of the '<br>' tag
breaks = re.findall('<br>|<br/>|<br />|\n', html)
print len(breaks)
```

Does that help?